# Hiding a PDF text by adding an extra layer

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i need to hide a text by adding a new layer over the text i need to hide.

```
public void ReplacePDFText(string strSearch, StringComparison scCase, string strSource, string strDest)
{
    PdfContentByte pCont = null;

    if (File.Exists(strSource)) {
        PdfReader pdfFileReader = new PdfReader(strSource);
        using (PdfStamper psStamp = new PdfStamper(pdfFileReader, new FileStream(strDest, FileMode.Create))) {
            for (int intCurrPage = 1; intCurrPage <= pdfFileReader.NumberOfPages; intCurrPage++) {
                LocTextExtractionStrategy Strategy = new LocTextExtractionStrategy();
                pCont = psStamp.GetUnderContent(intCurrPage);
                Strategy.UndercontentCharacterSpacing = pCont.CharacterSpacing;
                Strategy.UndercontentHorizontalScaling = pCont.HorizontalScaling;

                string currText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfFileReader, intCurrPage, Strategy);
                List<iTextSharp.text.Rectangle> lstMatches = Strategy.GetTextLocations(strSearch, scCase);

                PdfLayer pdLayer = default(PdfLayer);
                pdLayer = new PdfLayer("over", psStamp.Writer);
                pCont.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                foreach (Rectangle rctRect in lstMatches) {
                    pCont.Rectangle(rctRect.Left, rctRect.Bottom, rctRect.Width, rctRect.Height);
                    pCont.Fill();
                }
            }
        }
        pdfFileReader.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem with the approach above, is that the layer is added successfully with black color. So instead of the text i have a beautiful black line over the text.
But if i set the `pCont.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK)` to WHITE, the text is still displayed.
How can i overcome this issue?

Comment: hi....i also want to implement same logic of hiding text. I tried your code but  reference for class  LocTextExtractionStrategy Strategy = new LocTextExtractionStrategy(); is not found.....would you share your code with me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
pCont = psStamp.GetUnderContent(intCurrPage);
```

Use:

```
pCont = psStamp.GetOverContent(intCurrPage);
```